How to Handle Firebase Notifications in a Web App Embedded in a React Native WebView?
I'm working on a project where I have a React web app that is embedded within a React Native WebView. I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for handling notifications. The web app works fine when deployed on a secure domain (https://), but when I open the same web app in a WebView in my React Native app, I encounter the following error:

This browser doesn't support the API requested to use by Firebase SDK

Here's the Firebase configuration and token retrieval code I'm using in my React web app:
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/messaging';
import axios from 'axios';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyC9K1X3mSSw2d9RTVqBwBRy7ECtmkzJ4to",
  authDomain: "brotherize-654cf.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "brotherize-654cf",
  storageBucket: "brotherize-654cf.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "612370118030",
  appId: "1:612370118030:web:5a6bf0d77545330b2560df",
  measurementId: "G-4YSQ78M7VP",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

export const requestNotificationPermission = async () => {
  try {
    const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();
    if (permission === 'granted') {
      console.log('Notification permission granted.');
      getDeviceToken();
    } else {
      console.log('Notification permission denied.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error requesting notification permission:', error);
  }
};

const getDeviceToken = async () => {
  try {
    const currentToken = await messaging.getToken({
      vapidKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_KEY,
    });
    if (currentToken) {
      console.log('Device token:', currentToken);
      saveTokenToLocalStorage(currentToken);
      saveTokenToDb(currentToken);
    } else {
      console.log('No registration token available.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error getting device token:', error);
  }
};

const saveTokenToLocalStorage = (token: string) => {
  localStorage.setItem('device_token', JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token saved to local storage.');
};

const saveTokenToDb = async (token: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/v1/user/token', {
      deviceToken: token,
    });
    console.log('Token saved to database:', response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error saving token to database:', error);
  }
};

This code works perfectly in the web browser but fails when the web app is loaded within the WebView of my React Native app.

To solve this, some internal changes will be needed in the firebase npm package, in @firebase/app or similar (the module that helps the API to interact with the ReactApp environment), about three weeks ago there was a new commit added to the project, you could locally force these changes in the app directory for firebase only, there are several reasons for this to happen, one can be that Firebase Node Package itself can read where it is being accessed from and usually gets to API level interaction and the Browser detection gets wrong the Execution Environment:
More details on what to change in the code can be found here (or try using the new changes from 3 weeks ago): https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/pull/8315

Can you Please Share any method How i can locally push these changes in my project Package?

The Latest commit is already released in Package

I will try a proof of concept and get back soon

Hi did you find soluttion?
